# MySQL Error - Join tables from two different databases

Tags: mysql

**MySQL query**

```
select s.site_id,s.site_name,u.username 
FROM cloud_search.dbo.site_request s join user_db.dbo.user_info u 
on u.user_id=s.site_id;
```

**Error**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.site_request s join user_db.dbo.user_info u on u.user_id=s.site_id' at line 1

What am i doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using `dbo` it's usually for MSSQL

It's probably

```
select s.site_id,s.site_name,u.username FROM cloud_search.site_request s join user_db.user_info u on u.user_id=s.site_id;
```